# Custom setting Setting type not visible

Tags: picklist, customsetting

[image]I am trying to create a new custom setting in salesforce but the Setting Type field is greyed out and fixed to Hierarchy. What could be the possible problem?

Comment: weird, could you attach screenshot to your question?

Comment: I added the screenshot

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**You Can enable list custom setting schema Setting Page**

Setup > schema Setting Page > List custom Setting

Answer (score 4):

Please consider using custom metadata types instead of list custom settings. They are way more powerful: allow packaging of the records, support more field types, have better protection (on type, field and record level).

Comment: Could you point out more on this?

Comment: Please see some documentation here:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_overview.htm&type=5